# How to use cell reference in a cell with brackets in Excel 2007?

Tags: excel-2007

In Excel, I want to reference cell in a cell. how do I do this?
Ex: in cell A1, I will type md.resourcetyperef(1234567890), but I want to reference 1234567890 which is in another spreadsheet.

Thanks!
A

Answer (score 0):

Considering `md.resourcetyperef()` is your [UDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-defined_function), and `1234567890` is at `A1` cell in another sheet named `AnotherSheet` then try this:

`=md.resourcetyperef(AnotherSheet!A1)`